# how to use stackview for label and textfield together in which textfield has more length

Tags: ios, uistackview

I'm new to **stackviews**. I'm trying to build the following  using stack views.

[image]

But when I apply horizontal stackview to the label and textfield together the textfield's length is not as I required. I tried all the allignment and distribution combinations of horizontal stack view. But there is no result. Please help me. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add a stackview with axis property to vertical, and alignment property to Fill like this [image]

And then add a stackview with axis property to horozontal, and alignment property to Fill, and distribution also fill. Like this [image]

You will get idea of how to set your view accordingly.